# Efficient Way of Defining Multiple Functions of the Same Type

Tags: coq

I would like to avoid copying and pasting the parameters and return type of functions of the same type that I am trying to define. Since, in my opinion, that would be bad programming practice.

For example, I am defining the following functions:

```
Definition metric_non_negative {X : Type} (d : X -> X -> R) :=
  forall x y : X, (d x y) >= 0.

Definition metric_identical_arguments {X : Type} (d : X -> X -> R) :=
  forall x y : X, (d x y) = 0 <-> x = y.
```

I would like to be able to define both functions without repeatedly typing the redundancy:

```
{X : Type} (d : X -> X -> R)
```

I would also like to potentially define a third function, in which case the solution should generalize to the case where more than two functions of the same type are being defined. Is this possible, and how so?

Comment: Does `Section` mechanism not solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anton Trunov mentioned in his comment, it sounds exactly like you want to use a section:

```
Section Metric.

  Context {X: Type}.
  Variable (d: X -> X -> nat).

  Definition metric_non_negative :=
    forall x y : X, (d x y) >= 0.

  Definition metric_identical_arguments :=
    forall x y : X, (d x y) = 0 <-> x = y.

End Metric.
```

Note that I've used `Context` to make `X` an implicit argument; you can also use `Set Implicit Arguments.` and make it a `Variable` to let Coq set its implicitness automatically.